# Creating a function that results in only the initials of the strings

Tags: python, function

Having some trouble trying to figure out a function that output the initials of the 'phrase'.  This is what I have so far.  Thanks for the help!

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phase.split
    result = ""

    for word in words:
        result += 1
    return result

print(initials("United Nations"))           # Should be: UN
print(initials("United States of America")) # Should be: USOA
print(initials("Banana Boat")).              # Should be: BB
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code?  There are some typos in it that the error messages should give you some clues to address.

Comment: Btw, your indentation is broken. No need, indeed forbidden, to indent the `for`.

Comment: Instead of ```result +=1```, make result collect the first letter of each word.  You could slice (```word[:1]```) or just use the index of zero (```word[0]```).

Comment: Always try to run the code snippet in http://www.pythontutor.com/ to see the execution steps.

Comment: I understand the impulse to use S.O. for help with school homework but you should ponder if that is considered cheating. Also, your question would have benefited from describing what happened when you ran your code and what about the behavior confused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow the PO's logic, no additional changes for the structure. Just fix the errors:

```
def initials(phrase):
    #words = phase.split()
    result = ""

    for word in phrase.split():   # break the words
        result += word[0]         # get the first letter of each word
    return result

print(initials("United Nations"))           # Should be: UN
print(initials("United States of America")) # Should be: USOA
```

There could be more Pythonic way to achieve the same, but here try to answer the PO's question instead.

Or just one-liner, using generator like this:

```
phrase = 'United Nations'
inits = ''.join(w[0] for w in phrase.split())'  # `UN`
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel Hao, I appreciate the comments that explain each line of code.  This is very helpful.  And you suggestion to put the snippet into pythontutor was a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

String is just an array of characters, and in Python you can simply access the first position AKA [0] in a string:

```
def initials(phrase):
  words = phase.split()
  result = ""
    for word in words:
        result += word[0]
    return result
```

If you want all uppercase just use an .upper() in "word[0]".

Comment: You miss the calling to function - words = phrase.split().

Comment: Thanks @DanielHao, i just did an edit over OP's code and missed it! :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, the initial of a `word` is `word[0]`, but you want to capitalize, so just go

```
def initials(phrase):
    return ''.join(word[0].upper() for word in phrase.split())
```